# How to SSL Passthrough on HAProxy while routing based on full URL?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, https, http, haproxy

I'm new to HAProxy admin so it may be a stupid question. So I wanted to do SSL pass though on our HAProxy load balancer. The diagram look like this:

```
client -> HAProxy -> server
```

where, all arrows would be HTTPS ideally.

Now I'm aware that I would need to do `mode tcp` on HAProxy. However we route requests based on the full URL, i.e. both the `Host` and the path. For example, for `https://foo.bar.com/zzz`, we would need some logic to define a few `acl`s based on regex (`url_reg`) on both `foo.bar.com` and `/zzz`. Is it possible to achieve this in `mode tcp`? As far as I know in this mode HAProxy cannot see the headers at all so it wouldn't know about the `Host` (i.e. `foo.bar.com`)?

This seems like an easy enough setup but I couldn't find an exact answer on the internet since everyone has a different setup, so thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: SSL passthrough mode, so no decryption/encryptoion on HAProxy.

Comment: You can't use the full URL without decrypting. Except for ancient or defective clients, you can use hostname only, from the SNI extension rather than the Host: header. This is covered by existing Qs which you are supposed to look at; start with https://serverfault.com/questions/1078467/how-to-force-a-specific-routing-based-on-sni-in-haproxy and https://serverfault.com/questions/1116573/why-is-tcp-request-content-accept-frontend-instruction-is-required-for-proper